# How to remove GPU in Google Kubernetes cluster (GKE)

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I cannot find a way to remove GPU (accelerator resource) from Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) cluster. There is no official documentation on how to make change to it. Can you suggest a proper way to do so? The UI is gray out and it cannot allow me to make change from the console.

Here is the screenshot when I click to edit cluster.
[image: screenshot of GKE edit node]

Thank you

Comment: FYI, I use helm to deploy the cluster. But my coworker wrote it. Not sure whether I where I need to make change. I'm still new to GKE.

Comment: Is it not in the custom instance description? If you use a normal instance, you don't see GPUs...

Comment: @night-gold, Maybe the question is .. How can I edit instance type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot edit settings of a Node Pool once it is created.

You should create a new node pool with the settings you want (GPU, machine type etc) and delete the old node pool.

There's a tutorial on how to migrate to a new node pool smoothly here: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/migrating-node-pool If you don't care about pods terminating gracefully, you can create a new pool and just delete the old one.

You can find more content about this at https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-upgrading-your-clusters-with-zero-downtime.